# mysql stored procedure dynamic order by with mixed types

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a stored procedure into which i'm passing an "order" dynamically like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getStuff`(IN orderSQL VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SELECT id, name, createdate
    FROM mytable
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN orderSQL='id_desc' THEN CONCAT(id, '') END DESC,
        CASE WHEN orderSQL='id_asc' THEN CONCAT(id, '') END ASC,
        CASE WHEN orderSQL='name_desc' THEN name END DESC,
        CASE WHEN orderSQL='name_asc' THEN name END ASC,
        CASE WHEN orderSQL='date_desc' THEN CONCAT(createdate, '') END DESC,
        CASE WHEN orderSQL='date_asc' THEN CONCAT(createdate, '') END ASC
END
```

As you can see i'm converting all the non VARCHAR fields to VARCHAR using CONCAT, because mixing possible order types doesn't work as explained here https://web.archive.org/web/20211029044050/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/010704-1.shtml.

My issue is that now ordering by name works, but non string orders come back as 1,10,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. etc

Is there a way to use mixed datatype dynamic ordering, and still return in the correct order for ints, datetimes etc.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to create the SQL statement full dynamically like so

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GetStuff (IN orderSQL varchar(100) ) 
BEGIN

  DECLARE SQLStatement varchar(255);

  -- Enter the dynamic SQL statement into the
  -- variable @SQLStatement
  SET SQLStatement = CONCAT('SELECT id, name, createdate ',
                             'FROM mytable ',
                             'ORDER BY ',orderSQL);

  PREPARE stmt FROM SQLStatement;
  EXECUTE stmt;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

See here for more info: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html

Answer (score 2):

You should use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to build and execute custom query or you should write big CASE condition with all your queries, i.e. -

```
  CASE orderSQL
    WHEN 'id_desc' THEN
      SELECT id, name, createdate FROM mytable ORDER BY id;
    WHEN 'id_desc' THEN
      SELECT id, name, createdate FROM mytable ORDER BY id_desc;
    ...
    ...
    ...
  END CASE;
```

Comment: CASE is used only in expressions, no? So this should be a series of `IF … ELSE IF …`, I think.

Comment: These are different CASE statements. I used this one - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-statement.html.